# How to integrate Oauth authentication into a Active learning bot

Tags: c#, oauth, botframework, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-bot-service

I am building an activelearning bot from the samples provided in the Microsoft bot repository
specifically this one:

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/48.qnamaker-active-learning-bot

And I am also able to test and validate the example of using Graph api to authenticate and identify the user name, 
specifically through this sample:
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph

But I am unable to integrate these to together.

I see that I have to add the PromptStepAsync , but however I do not see a relevant place where I can add into the active learning bot sample

```
AddDialog(new OAuthPrompt(
    nameof(OAuthPrompt),
    new OAuthPromptSettings
    {
        ConnectionName = ConnectionName,
        Text = "Please login",
        Title = "Login",
        Timeout = 300000, // User has 5 minutes to login
    }));
```

I have tried changing the PromptStepAsync to below and adding it to DialogHelper.cs, but it errors out

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> PromptStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    //return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(OAuthPrompt), null, cancellationToken);
    return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
    nameof(OAuthPrompt),
        new OAuthPromptSettings
        {
            ConnectionName = "abc",
            Text = "Please login",
            Title = "Login",
            Timeout = 300000, // User has 5 minutes to login
        }
    , cancellationToken);
}
```

I eventually plan to answer the questions of users only who are successfully authenticated. Appreciate your help or direction.

Comment: Hi @KyleDelaney, I see that you have mentioned this bot to be different to other samples here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57658154/is-the-best-practice-alwayas-to-start-a-dialog-in-bot/57664701#57664701 , please can you advise a best way to achieve this?

Comment: You asked for my help and I helped you. Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in the authentication sample the `OAuthPrompt` process actually requires two waterfall steps, so you'll need both `PromptStepAsync` and `LoginStepAsync`. Because the user may already have signed in, the `OAuthPrompt` may not actually end the turn, in which case it would automatically continue on to the next step without prompting. I believe `OAuthPrompt` is designed to be used every time your bot needs to do something that requires a user token, so you may need to repeat this pattern in multiple places. Please refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication) for more information.

Also remember that if your bot isn't actually calling any API that requires a token and you just want to authenticate the user for your own sake then you may want to include logic in the bot that validates the token somehow.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So, is your suggestion to start off with a multi-dialogue example and then introduce the QnA and OAuthPrompt into that? Basically I am looking for a good starting point for my bot described above.

Comment: The Core Bot sample seems like a good enough starting point. The scenario you described above seems pretty simple. Remember that QnA bots don't really need dialogs at all as long as each question can be answered in a single turn. I imagine your onTurn handler will check to see if the user has logged in and if they haven't it will show the OAuthPrompt and if they have then it will answer their question. Also remember that Stack Overflow is for getting specific answers to specific questions and not for finding tutors or tutorials. Don't forget to accept this answer to the question you asked.